как изменить расположение элементов на форме при выборе определенного языка из меню
Мне нужно чтобы при выборе немецкого языка форма располагалась в вертикальном формате, но так при выборе у меня вылетает форма
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace labwork1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Clock oclock = new Clock();
        public Form1()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.Language);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(Properties.Settings.Default.Language);
            InitializeComponent();
            
            oclock.Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(ourTick);

        }
        void ourTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Properties.Resource.Date + oclock.CityTime("Moscow").ToShortDateString() + Properties.Resource.Time + oclock.CityTime("Moscow").ToLongTimeString();
            textBox2.Text = Properties.Resource.Date + oclock.CityTime("Vladivostok").ToShortDateString() + Properties.Resource.Time + oclock.CityTime("Vladivostok").ToLongTimeString();
            textBox3.Text = Properties.Resource.Date + oclock.CityTime("London").ToShortDateString() + Properties.Resource.Time + oclock.CityTime("London").ToLongTimeString();

        }

        private void btnStart(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oclock.ChangeAct(true);
        }

        private void btnStop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oclock.ChangeAct(false);
        }

        
        private void стартToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void стопToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStop(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        private void английскийToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
            Properties.Settings.Default.Language = "en";

            UpdateLanguage(); // убедитесь, что этот вызов обновляет все нужные элементы
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Application.Restart(); // это сбр
        }

        private void немецкийToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Location = new Point(100, 350); // Пример новой позиции
            button2.Location = new Point(300, 350);
            label1.Location = new Point(20, 30);
            label2.Location = new Point(20, 70);
            label3.Location = new Point(20, 110);
            textBox1.Location = new Point(12, 50);
            textBox2.Location = new Point(12, 90);
            textBox3.Location = new Point(12, 130);

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de");
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de");
            Properties.Settings.Default.Language = "de";
            UpdateLanguage();

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            Application.Restart();
        }

        private void UpdateLanguage()
        {
            button1.Text = Properties.Resource.Start; // текст на английском
            button2.Text = Properties.Resource.Stop;

            label1.Text = Properties.Resource.Moscow;
            label2.Text = Properties.Resource.London;
            label3.Text = Properties.Resource.Vladivostok;

            textBox1.Text = Properties.Resource.Date + oclock.CityTime("Moscow").ToShortDateString() + Properties.Resource.Time + oclock.CityTime("Moscow").ToLongTimeString();
            textBox2.Text = Properties.Resource.Date + oclock.CityTime("Vladivostok").ToShortDateString() + Properties.Resource.Time + oclock.CityTime("Vladivostok").ToLongTimeString();
            textBox3.Text = Properties.Resource.Date + oclock.CityTime("London").ToShortDateString() + Properties.Resource.Time + oclock.CityTime("London").ToLongTimeString();
        }


        private void русскийToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Смена на русский язык
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru");
        Properties.Settings.Default.Language = "ru";
            UpdateLanguage();
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        Application.Restart(); }
    }
    
}


Application.Restart(); - это как-то слишком, не? Это прям перезапуск приложения. А при выборе других языков не вылетает? А с какой ошибкой вылетает? Опишите полностью ситуацию.

Опишите ошибку/проблему целиком. Посмотрите, что происходит при выполнении кода в режиме отладки
